# Thymeleaf rejects null date

Tags: html, postgresql, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have this html code:

```
<input class="form-control col-sm-8" type="date" th:field="*{completiondate}">
```

and this model :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class EventReport {
    private Long id;
    private Date creationdate;
    private String status;
    private Date completiondate;
    ...
}
```

completion date is not a required value and can be null sometimes. When user submits the post form I take the following

> Field error in object 'treeTrimsEventReport' on field
>   'completiondate': rejected value [];

Obviously I don't have errors when I select a value for date and the app works fine. 
How can I give null on completion date without errors?

Comment: could you show the object annotations on the date field where this date is bound ?

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal" action = "#" th:action="@{/lights/insert}" th:object="${eventreport}" method="post">`

Comment: `import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class EventReport {

    private Long id;

    private Date creationdate;

    private String status;

    private Date completiondate;`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a binding error.

You need to tell spring how to convert form data which comes as text (`String`) to the type in your model (here a `Date`).

You may do it with this annotation on the field in `EventReport` :

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
...
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date completiondate;
```

(change the pattern to match the one you wish to show to the user)

Spring gives you other option to tell it how to bind data.

Have a look at the reference manual, in this chapter for all options :
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder